# Can GET(self,arg) in webpy take more than one argument other than self?

Tags: python, get, web.py

I have little trouble in undertanding how GET(self,arg) takes arguments from the URL.

I couldn't find any complete documentation or reference for webpy.
From my understanding, webpy takes arguments from the URL based on the rules we define:

`urls = ( '/something/(.*), 'some_class' )`

So if we supply url like `http://server.com/something/item`, the arg for GET will be `item`.

I have tried the following, but didn't work:

- `urls = ( /something/(.*), 'some_class' )`, `GET(self,arg1,arg2)` and  `http://server.com/something/item1/item2`
- `urls = ( /something/(.*)/(.*), 'some_class' )`, `GET(self,arg1,arg2)` and  `http://server.com/something/item1/item2`

So, what's happenig in the background and what are the rules that are defining how GET should take it's arguments. Does it take only one argumenta other than self?

**Update:**
Actually, the second example works. So, I think that's it. GET can take any number of arguments from URL.

Answer (score 1):

GET takes the same number of arguments as captures from the url (plus "self"). If you capture two bits `/something/(.*)/(.*)`, then GET takes self + 2 arguments.

You can use default values, if you want to use two different sets of URL but handle with the same `GET()`.

You can also match (but not capture) within the URL -- if you want to match a URL, but don't need to pass a portion on to your GET().

For example support url `/(dog|cat|pig)/([0-9]+)`, which would process URLs /dog/1, /cat/45, /pig/123 all with the same GET function: `GET(self, animal, code)`. Two captures, two (plus "self") values.

Maybe you don't need to pass in the first bit (because you handle any of these three animals the same way) so instead do url `/(?:dog|cat|pig)/([0-9]+)`. You then use `GET(self, code)`. This is useful to allow /zebra/234 to be processed using a different function. One capture, one (plus "self") values.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience in `web.py`, although it should be okay if the second value is provided a default value.

```
....
def GET(self, arg1, arg2 = None):
    ....
```

This may not work if `web.py` only actually passes a single argument to the GET function, which is most likely how it works.